# Outlook 2007: How to make all appointments "private" by default?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007, I can make an appointment "private" by clicking on Private (little lock symbol) in the Options area.

I would like to make all appointments Private by default.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to write a macro that processes all your appointments to do this, and set the Sensitivity property to olPrivate.